# Database first Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In ASP.NET there is entity framework or something called "database first," where entities are generated from an existing database. Is there something similar for Django?

I usually work with a pre-existing database that I need to create a backend (and subsequently a front end) for. Some of these relational databases have many tables and relations so manually writing models isn't a good idea. I've scoured Google for solutions but have come up relatively empty handed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the information on this link.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/
It depends on your database, but I've worked with it and is good.

Comment: Looks like there's one built into Django.. Not sure how I missed that in two days searching but I'm guessing "database first" is really only an ASP.NET thing. Search terms... I'll take a look and mark as correct if I have no follow ups. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The default in Django is a Code First-type approach where the Django framework engine creates a Db for you based on your models and uses migrations to update the Db with model changes (like Code First).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/

What you're describing sounds like a Database First approach in the .Net world.
Integrating Django with a legacy database:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: .NET has Code First as well with EF, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx .  Just FYI.