# How to connect to external MySQL without using models.py in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have my report dashboard that I'm developing using Django and I want to connect it to my MySQL database without using **models.py** or migrations.

Basically, here's what I've done so far.

**views.py**

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('db.ini')


def getConnection():
    host = config['ord']['host']
    port = config['ord']['port']
    database = config['ord']['database']
    password = config['ord']['password']
    user = config['ord']['user']
    
    connection = pymssql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print("Connection Succesfull")
    
    return cursor

def fill_weight(request):
    try:
        sql = u """
            SELECT * FROM fill_weight;
        """
        sql =sql.encode('utf-8')
        cursor.execute(sql)
        cursor.fetchall()
```

**db.ini**

```
[oof_ord]
host = localhost
port = 3306
database = xxxxxxxxxxx
user = xxxxxxxxxxx
password = xxxxxxxxxxx
default-character-set = utf8
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I don't have the official database that I'm going to use for this system and I want to easily access it by putting it's database credentials to my **db.ini** and access it to show the data without doing any migrations.
Is there anyone that can help me ?

Comment: you mean something like Database First ORM?

Comment: in your case `Flask` as **micro framework** would be the option that fits your needs.

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi Yes sir something like that.

Comment: @cizario Yah but the client requries me to use django for this

Comment: ok check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519220/7337499) out hope it helps